# How to convert the code from OkHttp to use the Apache Http?

Tags: java, okhttp, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am struggling to get an Post Request to return a 200 answer in my project. We have a Postman test, that is working fine and generates the following code:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
  .build();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
  .addFormDataPart("customerNumber","1000000")
  .addFormDataPart("username","razisami")
  .addFormDataPart("password","razisami1234")
  .build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("http://localhost:8085/ImageGateway/login")
  .method("POST", body)
  .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
'''
I need the same code written again to work with Apache HttpClient, see [Posting with HttpClient][1]


  [1]: https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-post-http-request
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the equivalent code with Apache HttpClient **5.1**, which I recommend to be used instead of HttpClient 4.5 for new projects

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createSystem();
ClassicHttpRequest request = ClassicRequestBuilder.post()
        .setUri(new URI("http://localhost:8085/ImageGateway/login"))
        .addParameter("customerNumber","1000000")
        .addParameter("username","razisami")
        .addParameter("password","razisami1234")
        .build();
httpclient.execute(request, response -> {
    // do something useful with the response
    return null;
});
```